# Access to XMLHttpRequest problems with Cors

Tags: node.js, express, ionic-framework, cors

I took an Ionic 5 course and when I did one of the exercises I wanted to put the backend written in JS inside github and heroku, when starting my authentication within my application it throws me the following error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8syH.png)

my backend is en node and express:

```
//allow cross config
server.app.use( cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }) );
server.app.use(function (req, res, next) {

// Website you wish to allow to connect
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

// Request headers you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'x-token, content-type');
next();
});
```

my app need to login and return one token per user, and this token is use in headers in other petitions

Answer (score -1):

To avoid CORS issues i think you should use native http requests in your ionic app.

That is the simpliest way to solve your issue in my point of view.